# I would like to know if my sentence is correct

Tags: word-usage

Can I say " I was going to have a swim earlier"?
I was told that I have to put "Earlier" at the beginning of the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is completely correct and idiomatic. The only reason why you might wish to put "earlier" at the beginning of the sentence would be if you wanted to emphasise that word for some reason.

Without context both sentences are potentially ambiguous because a lot of their meaning depends on whatever it is that is later than the intended swim.

Comment: Thanks JeremyC. I thought I was correct. I was told by someone that it was incorrect. I am an online English Teacher and presumed that it was correct.